# Weird waveform of a digital latch

Tags: clock, latch, edge

I am simulating on ADS.

As you can see, the V1 goes high at 9n sec.The clk has first rising edge at 10n sec.

Why does output V2 not go up at the 10n seconds? It goes up at 20n seconds at the second rising edge.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a simulator so the DFF has no setup time requirement, right?

Comment: ! yeah thank. it works when I have V1 go up earlier